# Building an modern webApp

Tags: reactjs, spring, authentication, architecture, microservices

I hope you are doing well.

I have a fundermental question to the experienced developers here.
I am planning to build a microservice web-application with java spring backend and react frontend.
I am experienced with java and I am learning react at the moment. I plan to host my application on my rancher single node cluster.

I have a few questions to some points I havent figured out yet(sry Im a newbee)

1. How should I manage the user-login system? I have already done some web-development and built a login-sys with php for example but I have no idea what to use for a microservice-application with spring and react. I mean every applaction needs a login system, is ther maybe already a "plug and play solution"?
2. Do you have some tips how to setup a database infrastructure for the project?
3. I want to start with the application as fast as possible. It does not need to be perfect. I just want to have a platform to test and collect some experience. What you think about the combination of sprint/react/rancher? Does anybody know a good guide to build an application like this?

I would be very happy if somebody can help me. Thank you for your answers and have a nice day.
:)

Best Mamo

Comment: Hi, first of all ask yourself if you will be managing passwords or you want to use a 3rd party such as google/apple/facebook etc. You could have a look at spring security or if you want to implement in-house I recommend you use a JWT based authentication. If you store passwords you should store them hashed in the database so you could only validate against them with a secrete key (that you want to have injected from configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend `keycloak` open source IAM for authentication and authorization.
In order to configure it:

- front end you can use `react-auth-config` library
- backend you can use `Spring Security`
  You can check [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak)  for Spring Boot and Keycloak:

This will give you token based authentication
For database, it is up to your entity relations. First you need to decide whether you need a relational one or not. Then you can consider several options
You can check [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-choose-the-right-database-for-your-application/)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that out imidiately